# Open a Woocommerce tab from a separate icon on the single product page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs

I need to add a custom functionality to a woocommerce single product page. The user needs to be able to click on an icon underneither the short description, which pops them down to the tab section, and opens the related tab.

Making it scroll down to the bottom is no problem, but opening the related tab I can not figure out. I have tried accessing the tab via URL (http://www.remicorson.com/access-woocommerce-product-tabs-directly-via-url/), but the problem with that is the page needs to reload. Any help I can get with this would be much appreciated.

Here is the code for the tabs I am working with:

```
function product_icon_set(){

    echo "<div class='info-panel'>
        <div class='learn_more img__wrap'>
            <a href='#description_tab'><img class='icon_product img__img' src='http://webdev/rbo/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Icon_MoreInformation_On.png.png' /></a>
            <p class='img__description'>Desc.</p>   
        </div>
        <div class='specs img__wrap'>
            <a href='#specifications'><img class='icon_product img__img' src='http://webdev/rbo/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Icon_Specifications_On.png.png' /></a>
            <p class='img__description'>Specs.</p>  
        </div>
        <div class='dimension img__wrap'>
            <a rel='prettyPhoto' title='My Picture 1' href='https://webdev/rbo/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ITD1013-Hanging-Hose-Rack-Dimensions.jpg'><img class='icon_product img__img' src='http://webdev/rbo/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Icon_Demensions_On.png.png' /></a>
            <p class='img__description'>Dimen.</p>
        </div>
        <div class='product_manual img__wrap'>
            <a href='#tabs_product'><img class='icon_product img__img' src='http://webdev/rbo/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Icon_OpsManual_On.png.png' /></a>
            <p class='img__description'>Manual</p>
        </div>
        <div class='tech_tips img__wrap'>
            <a href='#tabs_product'><img class='icon_product img__img' src='https://webdev/rbo/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Icon_Tech-Tips_On.png-copy.png' /></a>
            <p class='img__description'>Tech Tips</p>
        </div>
        <div class='instal_video img__wrap'>
            <a href='#tabs_product'><img class='icon_product img__img' src='https://webdev/rbo/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Installation_videos.png' /></a>
            <p class='img__description'>Instal.</p>
        </div>
    </div>";

}
```

To recap, the user will click on a tab, that brings them to the tab section, and opens the related tab. Ex. Click specs icon, pop down to the section, and open the specifications tab.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured this out through jquery. You need to create a function that remove the class "active" from the current Li, then add it to the Li that you want active (the tab with the correct class), then do the same to the corresponding div ID for the content. Here is the function, along with tab code I am using.

```
function wc_change_tab() {
if( is_product() ) {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            // Activate Description Tab
            $('.desc_tab_button').on('click', function () {
                //disable active tab
                $( 'li.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
                //enable desired tab
                $( 'li.' + 'description' + '_tab' ).addClass( 'active' );

                //disable active tab contents
                $( 'div.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
                //enable desired tab contents
                $( 'div#' + 'tab-description' ).addClass( 'active' );
              });

            // Activate Specs Tab
            $('.specs_tab_button').on('click', function () {
                //disable active tab
                $( 'li.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
                //enable desired tab
                $( 'li.' + 'additional_information' + '_tab' ).addClass( 'active' );

                //disable active tab contents
                $( 'div.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
                //enable desired tab contents
                $( 'div#' + 'tab-additional_information' ).addClass( 'active' );


            /*///// TEMPLATE FOR NEW ICON /// CHANGE OUT CLASS NAMES// Activate Specs Tab
            $('.CHANGE_TO_ICON_CLASS').on('click', function () {
                //disable active tab
                $( 'li.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
                //enable desired tab
                $( 'li.' + 'CHANGE_TO_TAB_CLASS_NAME' + '_tab' ).addClass( 'active' );

                //disable active tab contents
                $( 'div.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
                //enable desired tab contents
                $( 'div#' + 'CHANGE_TO_TAB_ID_NAME' ).addClass( 'active' );*/
              });

    });
    </script>
<?php
}
```

}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wc_change_tab', 26 );

```
// Icon Set
```

function product_icon_set(){

```
echo "<div class='info-panel'>
    <div class='learn_more img__wrap'>
        <a href='#tabs_product' class='desc_tab_button'><img class='icon_product img__img' src='http://webdev/rbo/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Icon_MoreInformation_On.png.png' /></a>
        <p class='img__description'>Desc.</p>   
    </div>
    <div class='specs img__wrap'>
        <a href='#tabs_product' class='specs_tab_button'><img class='icon_product img__img' src='http://webdev/rbo/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Icon_Specifications_On.png.png' /></a>
        <p class='img__description'>Specs.</p>  
    </div>
    <div class='dimension img__wrap'>
        <a rel='prettyPhoto' title='My Picture 1' href='https://webdev/rbo/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ITD1013-Hanging-Hose-Rack-Dimensions.jpg'><img class='icon_product img__img' src='http://webdev/rbo/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Icon_Demensions_On.png.png' /></a>
        <p class='img__description'>Dimen.</p>
    </div>
    <div class='product_manual img__wrap'>
        <a href='#tabs_product'><img class='icon_product img__img' src='http://webdev/rbo/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Icon_OpsManual_On.png.png' /></a>
        <p class='img__description'>Manual</p>
    </div>
    <div class='tech_tips img__wrap'>
        <a href='#tabs_product'><img class='icon_product img__img' src='https://webdev/rbo/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Icon_Tech-Tips_On.png-copy.png' /></a>
        <p class='img__description'>Tech Tips</p>
    </div>
    <div class='instal_video img__wrap'>
        <a href='#tabs_product'><img class='icon_product img__img' src='https://webdev/rbo/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Installation_videos.png' /></a>
        <p class='img__description'>Instal.</p>
    </div>
</div>";
```

}